# My customized view does not appear in landscape like it does in portrait mode

Tags: android, view

I am using a customized view extending android.view.View and in wich am drawing some pictures and texts. However, this view is shown normally in the activity in portrait mode but when rotating to the landscape mode its also shown with all its elements (pictures texts...)  but 
all those elements are nested ones up on others sol i like a way to show them in the same way as in the portrait mode

will be grateful for any help

Comment: Chances for help might increase if you'd post the code of your custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fragments. If you are not,  then you have to. Basically you'll need 2 layouts,  one for portrait, and other for landscape.  There's good number of articles on Google that show you how to do that. Here's an example:

```
  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. in fact i have had some search and so seen theses articles on Google for Fargments but could you please suggest me one ? the easiest ?

Comment: thnx a lot. i will see it